# C# List: Convert Many-to-many list to One-to-many list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am new to linq queries. 
I have following Linq query for fetching data from db, which returns me a many to many list of some entries and some documents.

```
var list = (                           
            from entry in dbContext1.Table1.ToArray()
            join mapping in dbContext2.Table2 on entry.ID equals mapping.ID into mp
            from mapping in mp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join document in dbContext2.Table3
            on mapping?.FileID equals document.FileId into dc
            from document in dc.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                Entry = entry,
                Document = document
            }
).ToList();
```

The Entry class has a member as below : `List<Document> documents`

I want convert this list to a one to many list i can access all the data from single list of entries.

I hope I am clear enough about my question.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, GroupBy() should help me, right?

Comment: Are you trying to eliminate duplicate Entries and/or Documents? Or are you trying to separate the Entry from the Document so you get one list of both entries and documents? Also, are both Entry and Document strings?

Comment: Groups are maybe what you want. Give us an example of what you want at the end.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful here.